# Dealing with null characters in stdin in C++

Tags: c++, string, google-chrome, stdin, null-terminated

I am writing an extension for Chrome that uses native host messaging. The goal is to have Chrome open links in the OS default browser when running in app mode. Chrome implements the native host messaging over pipes to stdin and stdout of the native application. This is all well and good and I've got the extension talking to the native application. The problem I'm having is that the first 4 bytes of data contain the length of the following string, which for my purposes will always contain null characters. An example strace is shown below. What is the best way to deal with this? I'd like to use something like cin or getline, that will stall the program until input is received if possible.

```
Process 27964 attached
read(0, "~\0\0\0\"http://stackoverflow.com/qu"..., 4096) = 130 
read(0,
```

This is the current C++ code. I've tried variations using cin.get and fgets, but they don't wait on input and Chrome kills the program after the loop runs amok.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    for(;;) {
        string message;
        cin >> message;
        if(!message.length()) break;
        string cmd(string("xdg-open ") + message);
        system(cmd.c_str());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-host-protocol), the length should be in native byte order,  so the same endianness that your compiler uses for the same CPU architecture:

> each message is serialized using JSON, UTF-8 encoded and is preceded
>   with 32-bit message length in native byte order.

This means that you could read first the length:

```
uint32_t len;  
while (cin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&len), sizeof (len))) // process the messages
{ 
    // you know the number of bytes in the message: just read them  
    string msg (len, ' ');  // string filled with blanks 
    if (!cin.read(&msg[0], len) ) 
        /* process unexpected error of missing bytes */;
    else /* process the message normally */   
}
```

Comment: Compiler doesn't like that.
`error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_istream<char>::read(uint32_t*, long unsigned int)’`
`note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘uint32_t* {aka unsigned int*}’ to ‘std::basic_istream<char>::char_type* {aka char*}’`

Comment: @spike.barnett Sorry:  a cast is needed to compy with read()'s expectatinos.  I've edited.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a bunch. Also, I didn't even know reinterpret_cast existed. I'll have to read up on that.

Comment: [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) some reading to start with.  But as its name suggests: this should be used with caution ;-)